# Running python script from php on heroku

Tags: python, php, heroku

I am currently making a web app using php and python, my goal is to run a python script from the php on heroku. I tried it already locally and it works but when I try to deploy it to heroku it doesn't work, the error is H12 Request Timeout when i open the heroku app.

my php looks like this

```
$result = exec("python script.py");

echo $result;
```

and inside of my python script is this

```
print("hello")
```

and inside my profile is

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

can anyone help me with this problem, I tried to look for a solution already but still I haven't found the solution to this problem.

Comment: Check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Answer (score 0):

It look like these applications should be split into two separate codebases.

Anyway,  take a look this with the multi-buildpack:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app